# Binder got null and toast killed

Tags: android, android-studio

I am making a to do list in android studio and my note editor is show binder got null and after that it kills my toast

This is the error I got:

Expecting binder but got null!

Input channel object 'c753b7d Toast (client)' was disposed without first being removed with the input manager!
Toast already killed. pkg=com.example.assigment2 token=android.os.BinderProxy@3c3b57f

I have tried initializing a value first so that it will not be null. I have also tried moving the toasted around but it cant seem to fix the problem.

sorry if my code is hard to read:

```
private ArrayList<Task> notes = new ArrayList<>();


private EditText editTextTitle;
private EditText editTextDescription;
private Button buttonPending;
private Button buttonInProgress;
private Button buttonCompleted;
private String noteStatus;
private int noteId;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_note_editor);

    notes.add(new Task("random", "random", "Pending"));

    // Retrieve saved note data from SharedPreferences
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(
            "com.example.assignment2", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    noteId = sharedPreferences.getInt("note_id", -1);
    String noteTitle = sharedPreferences.getString("note_title", "");
    String noteDescription = sharedPreferences.getString("note_description", "");
    noteStatus = sharedPreferences.getString("note_status", "Pending");

    // Find views by ID
    editTextTitle = findViewById(R.id.editTextTitle);
    editTextDescription = findViewById(R.id.editTextDescription);
    buttonPending = findViewById(R.id.buttonPending);
    buttonInProgress = findViewById(R.id.buttonInProgress);
    buttonCompleted = findViewById(R.id.buttonCompleted);

    // Set the text of the title and description editTexts to the saved note data
    editTextTitle.setText(noteTitle);
    editTextDescription.setText(noteDescription);

    // Set the note status to the saved note status
    switch (noteStatus) {
        case "In Progress":
            setNoteStatus("In Progress");
            break;
        case "Completed":
            setNoteStatus("Completed");
            break;
        default:
            setNoteStatus("Pending");
            break;
    }

    // Set click listeners for the status buttons
    buttonPending.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setNoteStatus("Pending");
        }
    });

    buttonInProgress.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setNoteStatus("In Progress");
        }
    });

    buttonCompleted.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setNoteStatus("Completed");
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    // Save the note data to SharedPreferences
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(
            "com.example.assignment2", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

    editor.putString("note_title", editTextTitle.getText().toString());
    editor.putString("note_description", editTextDescription.getText().toString());
    editor.putString("note_status", noteStatus);
    if (noteId != -1 && noteId < notes.size()) { // Check if noteId is valid
        editor.putInt("note_id", noteId);
    }
    editor.apply();

    Log.d("note_editor", "Note saved to SharedPreferences");
}

public void setNoteStatus(String noteStatus) {
    this.noteStatus = noteStatus;
    switch (noteStatus) {
        case "Pending":
            buttonPending.setSelected(true);
            buttonInProgress.setSelected(false);
            buttonCompleted.setSelected(false);
            break;
        case "In Progress":
            buttonPending.setSelected(false);
            buttonInProgress.setSelected(true);
            buttonCompleted.setSelected(false);
            break;
        case "Completed":
            buttonPending.setSelected(false);
            buttonInProgress.setSelected(false);
            buttonCompleted.setSelected(true);
            break;
        default:
            buttonPending.setSelected(false);
            buttonInProgress.setSelected(false);
            buttonCompleted.setSelected(false);
            break;
    }
}

public void saveNoteData(View view) {
    String title = editTextTitle.getText().toString();
    String description = editTextDescription.getText().toString();

    if (!title.isEmpty() && !description.isEmpty()) {
        Task task;
        if (noteId != -1 && noteId < notes.size()) { 
            task = notes.get(noteId);
            task.setTitle(title);
            task.setDescription(description);
            task.setStatus(noteStatus);
        } else {
            task = new Task(title, description, noteStatus);
            notes.add(task);
            noteId = notes.indexOf(task);
        }

        // Write the note data to XML file
        writeNotesToXml();

        Toast.makeText(this, "Note saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter a title and description", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

private void writeNotesToXml() {
    try {
        File file = new File(getFilesDir(), "notes.xml");
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);

        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = Xml.newSerializer();
        xmlSerializer.setOutput(fos, "UTF-8");
        xmlSerializer.startDocument(null, Boolean.TRUE);
        xmlSerializer.startTag(null, "notes");

        for (Task task : notes) {
            xmlSerializer.startTag(null, "note");

            xmlSerializer.startTag(null, "title");
            xmlSerializer.text(task.getTitle());
            xmlSerializer.endTag(null, "title");

            xmlSerializer.startTag(null, "description");
            xmlSerializer.text(task.getDescription());
            xmlSerializer.endTag(null, "description");

            xmlSerializer.startTag(null, "status");
            xmlSerializer.text(task.getStatus());
            xmlSerializer.endTag(null, "status");

            xmlSerializer.endTag(null, "note");
        }

        xmlSerializer.endTag(null, "notes");
        xmlSerializer.endDocument();
        xmlSerializer.flush();
        fos.close();

        Log.d("note_editor", "Notes saved to XML file");

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // Create a new intent to send the note data back to the MainActivity
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
    resultIntent.putExtra("note_title", "title");
    resultIntent.putExtra("note_description", "description");



    // Set the result of the activity to RESULT_OK and send the intent back
    setResult(RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
    finish();

}
```

}